# No such thing as density in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, equivalence-principle

In this paper from [Wang, 2016](http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/13/329-02-1605.04968.pdf), it is stated (pg. 3) that a consequence of the equivalence principle is that *there is no density for gravitation*.

**Can anyone expand on why this should be so?**

In the paper it is explained as "*at any
point in spacetime, one can choose a normal coordinate system so that all
first derivatives of the Lorentzian metric $\bar{g}$ vanish at this point."*, but I am not overly clear on what this means exactly.

Clearly, there are masses in GR and it seems reasonable that we can define a volume for a given spacetime/metric. Consequently, it seems that we can then determine a density, but obviously I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: There is some quantity called density. In fact, any scalar multiplied by $\sqrt{-g}$ is a density. And there indeed exists the so-called normal coordinate system in which $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and $\partial_\mu g_{\nu\rho}=0$ at a particular point. But this does not kill the concept of density.

Comment: The author is trying to argue that there is no such thing as **gravitational energy density**. We would expect such a quantity to be built from first derivatives of the metric, just as the energy density of a string under tension is built from first derivatives of the displacement, but such a quantity could always be set locally to zero by a judicious coordinate choice.

Comment: But is the $T_{00}$ component of the stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu \nu}$ not identified as the energy density?

Comment: That is the energy density of matter and radiation, which is the source of the gravitational field, not the energy density of the gravitational field itself.

Comment: @gj255 that could be a perfectly good answer.